# Как сделать своё стандартное меню (с пунктами О нас, Контакты и т.д.) в Opencart?

Tags: php, cms, opencart, меню

Нужно, чтобы добавлялся класс .active к выбранному пункту.

В месте, где стоит стандартное меню код:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          <?php foreach (array_chunk($category['children'], ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column'])) as $children) { ?>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <?php foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="see-all"><?php echo $text_all; ?> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a> </div>
    </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Можно было бы вместо него просто добавить свой код с ссылками, но как сделать что бы класс .active переключался?

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>"><?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?></a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Надо понять, какое условие применяется для класса .active, и прописать через if-else.

Answer (score 1):

Способ для меню категорий. Я описываю случай с дефолтным шаблоном, в кастомных сборках некоторые моменты могут отличаться. Но если вы работаете с OC - разберётесь.

в **header.php**, в цикле формирования меню категорий

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    ...
}
```

добавьте:

```
// проверяем запрос категории (достаём её id)
// и сравниваем с категориями в цикле наполнения массива $categories.
// в случае совпадения присваиваем значение переменной несущей имя активного класса
$class = '';
if(isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
    if ($category['category_id'] == $this->request->get['path']) {
        $class = ' top-menu-active';
    }               
}
```

и саму переменную `$class` подставьте в определение массива данных категории:

```
// Level 1
$data['categories'][] = array(
    'name'        => $category['name'],
    'children'    => $children_data,
    'column'      => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id']),
    'class'       => $class, // <--
    'image'       => $category['image'],
    'category_id' => $category['category_id']
);
```

в **header.tpl** добавьте вывод переменной `$class` для элемента списка меню - категории:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li class="dropdown<?=$category['class']?>">
        ....
```

Таким образом для элемента меню активной категории будет добавляться пользовательский класс.